# Measurable in functions (equal state)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Let $f: \Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R $ with this properties:
>
> $\forall \epsilon >0$ , $\exists U\subset\Bbb R$ , $U$ is open set,  s.t.$m(U)<\epsilon$ , $f$ is continuous on $ \Bbb R$\ $U$
>
> How to prove that $f$ is measurable on $\Bbb R$.

in this question: measurable i.e. lebesgue-measurable.

we must be prove: $f$ is measurable i.e. if $\alpha $ is arbitrary then $\{ x \in \Bbb R | f(x) > \alpha \} $ is measurable.

$m :$ {measurable} $\rightarrow \Bbb R$, and $U$ is open set , so $m(U)$ is well-defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every $n$, take an open set $U_n$ of measure $m(U_n)<1/n$ and such that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}\setminus U_n$. In particular, $f$ is measurable on $\mathbb{R}\setminus U_n$.

The set $V=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty U_n$ has measure $m(V)=0$. It's complement is $\mathbb{R}\setminus (\bigcap U_n)=\bigcup(\mathbb{R}\setminus U_n)$. Since $f$ is measurable on each $\mathbb{R}\setminus U_n$, then $f$ is measurable on $\mathbb{R}\setminus V$ (for each borel set $W$, we have $f|_{\mathbb{R}\setminus V}^ {-1}(W)=\bigcup(f|_{\mathbb{R}\setminus U_n}^{-1}(W))$, a countable union of measurable sets, hence measurable).

Since $V$ has measure $0$ and $f$ is measurable on $\mathbb{R}\setminus V$, then $f$ is measurable (if $W$ is a borel set, then $f^{-1}(W)=(f|_{\mathbb{R}\setminus V}^{-1}(W))\cup(f|_V^{-1}(W))$. We already know that $f|_{\mathbb{R}\setminus V}^{-1}(W)$ is measurable, and $f|_V^{-1}(W)$ is a subset of $V$, hence has measure $0$ and thus it is measurable, since the Lebesgue measure is complete).

Comment: Nice, Just one problem: Why $f$ is measurable on $\Bbb R$ \ $U_n$? (we have $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$ \ $U_n$)

Comment: this reason is true?  $\{ x \in \Bbb R$ \ $U_n | f(x) > \alpha \} $=$\{ x \in \Bbb R $ \ $U_n| inf (sup)_{t \rightarrow x } f(t) > \alpha \} $ and right set is measurable.

Comment: @agustin $\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus U_n:f(x)>\alpha\right\}$ is the preimage of the open set $(\alpha,\infty)$ under the continuous function $f$, hence it is open, Borel, Lebesgue.